# Installing SQLServer express 2005 Reporting Services after VS 2008/2010 install

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, sql-server-express

I installed SQL Server Express 2005 a few years ago. Since then I've installed Visual Studio 2008/2010 Express, which installed SOME SSE 2008 components on my machine (Management Objects). Now, I want to go back and install the SQL Server Reporting Server component (part of 2005 Express Edition Toolkit) into my 2005 installation. The installer's System Configuration Check is successful/all tests pass. But then the installer reports that a component on my machine (Workstation components and development tools 9.3.4035.00) is newer than the one in the 2005 package, and can't continue. Says my "upgrade is blocked". So is there a workaround for installing the 2005 Reporting Server stuff if I've got some SSE 2008 stuff also on the machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quick answer is that the 2005 and 2008 SQL EXPRESS tools share a directory.  This means that although you can have instances of both running on your machine, you can only use the tools from one.

SO, you have a choice.  Either uninstall all sql 2008 express components and go 2005.. Or just install the sql 2008 stuff.